# Cannot save data in mongoDb collection : "ReferenceError: Model is not defined"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to save a model to a mongoDb collection but keep getting this "ReferenceError: Model is not defined"

The code in the model file looks like this :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const MetainfoSchema = new Schema({


  portfolio: {
    title: String,
    subTitle: String,
  },
  cv: {
    title: String,
    subTitle: String,
  },
  contact: {
    title: String,
    subTitle: String,
  }



}, { collection: "metainfo" });

const Metainfo = mongoose.model('Metainfo', MetainfoSchema);

const mModel = new Metainfo({

  portfolio: {
    title: "Portfolio",
    subTitle: "Checkout my works",
  },
  cv: {
    title: "Download my cv",
    subTitle: "Aviable in three languages",
  },
  contact: {
    title: "Let's talk",
    subTitle: "Send me an e-mail"
  }



});
mModel.save(function (err, doc) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log("Document inserted succussfully!");
});

module.exports = Metainfo;
```

When trying to save the model it appears as undefined but I did use mongoose.model to define it, I've been trying to find a fix but with no success .

Error :

```
[server] ReferenceError: Model is not defined
[server]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\andpa\Desktop\files\Projects\REACT\portfolio2020\server.js:32:16)
[server]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
[server]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
[server]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
[server]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
[server]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
[server]     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Please Help

Server.js  :

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const path = require("path");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const routes = require("./routes/api");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/portfolioDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
  console.log("Mongoose is connected");
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}

app.use(morgan("tiny"));
app.use("/api", routes);

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server is runing at ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: Share your `server.js` file. It seems some import is causing error.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari Added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new Model like below, before create a new **Metainfo**

```
mongoose.model('Metainfo', MetainfoSchema);
const Metainfo = mongoose.model('Metainfo');
```

after this you can create a model

```
const mModel = new Metainfo({
  portfolio: {
    title: "Portfolio",
    subTitle: "Checkout my works",
  },
  cv: {
    title: "Download my cv",
    subTitle: "Aviable in three languages",
  },
  contact: {
    title: "Let's talk",
    subTitle: "Send me an e-mail"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the model this way.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    autoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose);
const BreakReasonSchema = require('../models/BreakReason');

const UserInfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number
    },
    company_name_id: {
        type: Number
    },
    country_name_id: {
        type: Number
    },
    user_type_id: {
        type: Number
    },
    user_email: {
        type: String
    },
    user_pass: {
        type: String
    },
    first_name: {
        type: String
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String
    },
    user_mobile: {
        type: String
    },
    account_owner: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    account_owner: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    added_date: {
        type: Date
    },
    update_date: {
        type: Date
    },
    delete_date: {
        type: Date
    },
    delete_status: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    user_social_uid: {
        type: String
    },
    status: {
        type: Boolean
    }

}, {timestamps: true});
UserInfoSchema.virtual('break_reason_info', {
    ref: BreakReasonSchema,
    localField: 'company_name_id',
    foreignField: 'company_name_id'
});
UserInfoSchema.virtual('social_account_info', {
    ref: 'businessapp_companysocialaccountinfo',
    localField: 'company_name_id',
    foreignField: 'company_name_id'
});
UserInfoSchema.virtual('business_setup_info',{
    ref: 'businessapp_businesssetup',
    localField: 'company_name_id',
    foreignField: 'company_name_id',
    justOne:true
});
UserInfoSchema.set('toObject', {virtuals: true});
UserInfoSchema.set('toJSON', {virtuals: true});
//UserInfoSchema.plugin(autoIncrement, {id: "UserInfo", inc_field: 'id'});
module.exports = mongoose.model("businessapp_userinfo", UserInfoSchema, 'businessapp_userinfo');
```